# Why does ffmpeg report different durations?

Tags: video, ffmpeg

Source videos: http://www.artworknotavailable.com/tmp/ffmpegtest

Quicktime Pro 7.7.1 Inspector (Win 7) reports the following for the file 2398.mov

> 4.19MB
>   H.264
>   Movie FPS: 23.98
>   Data Rate: 2.35 mbits/Sec
>   Duration 14:97

ffmpeg reports the following (see full ffmpeg version info at bottom of post)

> ffmpeg -i 2398.mov
>
> Seems stream 1 codec frame rate differs from container frame rate: 47952.00 (47952/1) -> >23.98 (2997/125)
>   Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from '2398.mov':
>    Metadata:
>      major_brand     : qt
>
> > minor_version   : 537199360
> >        compatible_brands: qt
> >      Duration: 00:00:15.97, start: 0.-963005, bitrate: 2210 kb/s
> >        Stream #0.0(eng): Audio: aac, 48000 Hz, stereo, s16, 152 kb/s
> >        Stream #0.1(eng): Video: h264, yuv420p, 848x480, 2060 kb/s, 23.98 fps, 23.98 tbr, 23976 tbn, 47952 tbc

One second longer than what Quicktime reports.

As an experiment I exported this file from Quicktime Pro using the following settings:

> Frame Rate: Current
>   Key Frames: Every 24 frames
>   Frame Reordering On
>   Quality: High
>   Encoding Best
>   Data Rate: Automatic
>   Optimized for Download
>   Output file: qtime-export-2398.mov

Quicktime Inspector reports:

> 5.62 MB
>   H.264
>   Movie FPS: 23.98
>   Data Rate: 3.15 mbits/Sec
>   Duration 14:97

ffmpeg now reports:

> ffmpeg -i qtime-export-2398.mov
>
> Seems stream 1 codec frame rate differs from container frame rate: 1200.00 (1200/1) -> 23.98 (24000/1001)
>   Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'qtime-export-2398.mov':
>    Metadata:
>      major_brand     : qt
>      minor_version   : 537199360
>      compatible_brands: qt
>    Duration: 00:00:14.96, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 3153 kb/s
>      Stream #0.0(eng): Audio: pcm_s16le, 44100 Hz, 2 channels, s16, 1411 kb/s
>      Stream #0.1(eng): Video: h264, yuv420p, 678x384, 1738 kb/s, 23.98 fps, 23.98 tbr, 600 tbn, 1200 tbc

ffmpeg's report on duration went from 15.97 to 14.96 (I can live with .1)

Is this duration calculated from the bitrate?

I need to accurately report the duration of uploaded videos as well as convert them to FLV. Can somebody tell me what is going on here and how I might get around this?

ffmpeg info below. I've tried this on 2 completely different installs/versions of ffmpeg. Same result.

> FFmpeg version 0.6.5, Copyright (c) 2000-2010 the FFmpeg developers
>     built on Jan 29 2012 23:55:02 with gcc 4.1.2 20080704 (Red Hat 4.1.2-51)
>     configuration: --prefix=/usr --libdir=/usr/lib64 --shlibdir=/usr/lib64 --mandir=/usr/share/man --incdir=/usr/include --disable-avisynth --extra-cflags='-O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -m64 -mtune=generic -fPIC' --enable-avfilter --enable-avfilter-lavf --enable-libdirac --enable-libfaac --enable-libfaad --enable-libfaadbin --enable-libgsm --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libx264 --enable-gpl --enable-nonfree --enable-postproc --enable-pthreads --enable-shared --enable-swscale --enable-vdpau --enable-version3 --enable-x11grab
>     libavutil     50.15. 1 / 50.15. 1
>     libavcodec    52.72. 2 / 52.72. 2
>     libavformat   52.64. 2 / 52.64. 2
>     libavdevice   52. 2. 0 / 52. 2. 0
>     libavfilter    1.19. 0 /  1.19. 0
>     libswscale     0.11. 0 /  0.11. 0
>     libpostproc   51. 2. 0 / 51. 2. 0
>   FFmpeg 0.6.5
>   libavutil     50.15. 1 / 50.15. 1
>   libavcodec    52.72. 2 / 52.72. 2
>   libavformat   52.64. 2 / 52.64. 2
>   libavdevice   52. 2. 0 / 52. 2. 0
>   libavfilter    1.19. 0 /  1.19. 0
>   libswscale     0.11. 0 /  0.11. 0
>   libpostproc   51. 2. 0 / 51. 2. 0

Comment: Just tested with a few more variations in Quicktime export. It seems that if just pick any frame rate or bitrate to export, ffmpeg still has a much better chance of reporting a more accurate duration. Is Quicktime "Fixing" something? The container?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I just had a look at the first file and here is why they report a different duration.

Quicktime is collecting the duration value from the "movie header". The values here are 8981 / 600 = 14.97 seconds.

FFmpeg is collecting the duration value from the "media header" which is 383000 / 23976 = 15.97 seconds for the video and 719872 / 48000 = 15.00s for the audio.

Edit: ...and to also answer your other question: *Can somebody tell me how I might get around this?* I imagine you are using ffmpeg to convert the files to .FLV? If so, I would stick to what ffmpeg reports.

Comment: Thanks for the info. what's the best way to examine a QT file's movie header?

Comment: I'm also finding that if I use the '-ss' param and apply the negative start time reported by ffmpeg my file is closer to what I believe to be the correct duration, plus any audio that has been out of sync appears to be resolved. For example:

ffmpeg reports video input.mov 
start: 0.-963005
duration: 00:00:15.97

ffmpeg -i input.mov -ar 22050 -ab 65536 -s 320x240 -b 524288 -r 12 -ss 00:00:00.963005  output.flv

result:
Duration: 00:00:15.00

sorry, the stackoverflow comment box is driving me nuts.

Comment: Not sure what the best method is. I use a custom proprietary library I've built from scratch. Regarding the sync issue, you could also have a look at -async parameter and see if that helps. I think ffmpeg's reported duration may be correct for this file. If you put the file on a timeline which is not based on Quicktime components, such as Adobe Premiere Pro, the reported duration is 15 seconds and 23 frames.

Comment: Thanks. You've pretty much answered my initial question. I'll mark it shortly. I think the time might differ in an editing tool if you're timeline doesn't match the frame rate of the source video, no? In my mind, the actual time a Quicktime .mov plays back should be THE duration of the video. Also, VLC Media player says 00:14. So I am stuck with what is actually happening in real time or what a piece of software is saying it is. I'd like to believe what is actually happening. But that doesn't seem possible here.

Comment: I know this was nearly 5 years ago, but I wanted to add that I ran into this with a couple of movie trailer mp4 files, only the videos DID continue to play beyond the ffmpeg reported time. However, the actual 'video' ended at ffmpeg's time and what continued was a poster on one mp4 file and just a black screen on the other mp4.

Answer (score 1):

FFmpeg shows "Duration: 00:00:14.96" here, please understand that your version of FFmpeg is ancient (and has many known bugs and regressions), please see http://ffmpeg.org/download.html for information on how to get current git head, which is always recommended.

Comment: Thanks for the info cehoyos. Unfortunately, like a lot of folks out there, upgrading is not as simple as one might hope with the current infrastructure. The current version we have in production doesn't even have a version number. The examples I am using to test with here are from a personal shared hosting account I have through site5.com.